# JTextField not working as it should

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to make a simple calculator using Java. Code that I used for creating GUI is below.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, plus, minus,
            multiply, divide, equalTo, point;
    private JPanel panelForResult, panelForKeys;
    private JLabel Result;
    private JTextField result;

    public Calculator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {


        Calculator calcFrame = new Calculator();
        calcFrame.setSize(330, 400);
        calcFrame.setVisible(true);
        calcFrame.setResizable(false);
        calcFrame.createCalcGUI();

    }

    private void createCalcGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setBackground(Color.blue);
        window.setSize(400, 400);

        FlowLayout windowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        windowLayout.setHgap(50);
        window.setLayout(windowLayout);


        panelForKeys = new JPanel();
        panelForKeys.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        panelForKeys.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 250));

        FlowLayout buttonLayout = new FlowLayout();
       // buttonLayout.setAlignOnBaseline(true);
        panelForKeys.setLayout(buttonLayout);

        panelForResult = new JPanel();
        panelForResult.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        panelForResult.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        panelForResult.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        Result = new JLabel("=");
        result = new JTextField();

        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");
        zero = new JButton("0");
        plus = new JButton("+");
        minus = new JButton("-");
        multiply = new JButton("*");
        divide = new JButton("÷");
        equalTo = new JButton("=");
        point = new JButton(". ");




        one.addActionListener(this);
        two.addActionListener(this);
        three.addActionListener(this);
        four.addActionListener(this);
        five.addActionListener(this);
        six.addActionListener(this);
        seven.addActionListener(this);
        eight.addActionListener(this);
        nine.addActionListener(this);
        zero.addActionListener(this);
        plus.addActionListener(this);
        minus.addActionListener(this);
        divide.addActionListener(this);
        multiply.addActionListener(this);
        equalTo.addActionListener(this);
        point.addActionListener(this);

        panelForKeys.add(one);
        panelForKeys.add(two);
        panelForKeys.add(three);
        panelForKeys.add(four);
        panelForKeys.add(five);
        panelForKeys.add(six);
        panelForKeys.add(seven);
        panelForKeys.add(eight);
        panelForKeys.add(nine);
        panelForKeys.add(zero);
        panelForKeys.add(minus);
        panelForKeys.add(plus);
        panelForKeys.add(multiply);
        panelForKeys.add(divide);
        panelForKeys.add(equalTo);
        panelForKeys.add(point);


         window.add(panelForResult);
         window.add(this.panelForKeys);

      panelForResult.add(Result);
       panelForResult.add(result);


    }
}
```

Whenever I create the instance of `JTextField` and add it in the `panelForResult` the whole container window gets blue. If I comment `JTextField` out then it works. I am just a beginner of Java and may I know the possible cause for this and how to correct it?

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary code and try to make it: sscce.org

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your code and it is hard to provide an exact answer. Here are a few things to work on:

- `JFrame.setVisible(true)` should be your last call (set up the UI before calling it, or make sure to call `pack()` afterwards)
- Don't force `preferredSize`(don't ever call `setPreferredSize`). This is likely the cause of your issues. Always use an appropriate `LayoutManager`.
- Don't rely on `FlowLayout` to perform component wrapping.
- Provide a size hint to the `JTextField` by setting the number of columns
- Invoke all Swing-related code on the EDT (do it using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Here is a working example of your code (not sure though that it meets the layout you have in mind):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, plus, minus, multiply, divide, equalTo, point;
    private JPanel panelForResult, panelForKeys;
    private JLabel Result;
    private JTextField result;

    public Calculator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Calculator calcFrame = new Calculator();
                calcFrame.createCalcGUI();
                calcFrame.setResizable(false);
                calcFrame.pack();
                calcFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    private void createCalcGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setBackground(Color.blue);

        BoxLayout windowLayout = new BoxLayout(window, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        window.setLayout(windowLayout);

        panelForKeys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3, 5, 5));
        panelForKeys.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        panelForResult = new JPanel();
        panelForResult.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        panelForResult.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Result = new JLabel("=");
        result = new JTextField(12);

        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");
        zero = new JButton("0");
        plus = new JButton("+");
        minus = new JButton("-");
        multiply = new JButton("*");
        divide = new JButton("÷");
        equalTo = new JButton("=");
        point = new JButton(". ");

        one.addActionListener(this);
        two.addActionListener(this);
        three.addActionListener(this);
        four.addActionListener(this);
        five.addActionListener(this);
        six.addActionListener(this);
        seven.addActionListener(this);
        eight.addActionListener(this);
        nine.addActionListener(this);
        zero.addActionListener(this);
        plus.addActionListener(this);
        minus.addActionListener(this);
        divide.addActionListener(this);
        multiply.addActionListener(this);
        equalTo.addActionListener(this);
        point.addActionListener(this);

        panelForKeys.add(one);
        panelForKeys.add(two);
        panelForKeys.add(three);
        panelForKeys.add(four);
        panelForKeys.add(five);
        panelForKeys.add(six);
        panelForKeys.add(seven);
        panelForKeys.add(eight);
        panelForKeys.add(nine);
        panelForKeys.add(zero);
        panelForKeys.add(minus);
        panelForKeys.add(plus);
        panelForKeys.add(multiply);
        panelForKeys.add(divide);
        panelForKeys.add(equalTo);
        panelForKeys.add(point);

        window.add(panelForResult);
        window.add(this.panelForKeys);

        panelForResult.add(Result);
        panelForResult.add(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This most likely happens because you're making the GUI on the main thread, instead of the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Swing components should only be accessed on the Event Dispatch Thread. This can be achieved by calling [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html).

In your case, change your main method to this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calculator calcFrame = new Calculator();
            calcFrame.setSize(330, 400);
            calcFrame.setVisible(true);
            calcFrame.setResizable(false);
            calcFrame.createCalcGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:
In Java, there's something called threads. By using multiple threads, you can have multiple pieces of code running at the same time, which could increase efficiency.

However, not all code can safely run on different threads at the same time. For instance, Swing components. Swing components should only be accessed on a specific thread called the Event Dispatch Thread.

You can read more about threads [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: @Leone nebula It works now. thanks but may i know what is Event Dispatch Thread in detail.

Comment: @user2398618 I added some info about threads and the Event Dispatch Thread.